# Package ‘rcompanion’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the package "rcompanion", but it says "Warning in install.packages : package ‘rcompanion’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)".

I have tried the following, but with no success:

install.packages("rcompanion")
install.packages("rcompanion", repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')

Can anyone help, please?

It's a very important package for the analysis that I'm doing.

Thank you!

Comment: According to the [CRAN page for that pacakge](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rcompanion), you need to use at least R version 4.1 and you seem to be using R 3.6.3. If you want to use the latest version of that package, you'll need to update your copy of R.

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick! Problem resolved by updating my R.